# leaflet equirectangular projection

Tags: leaflet

I'd like to have my map display in equirectangular mode rather than the default mercator. How can I do this? Here is my code:

```
<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.css"/>
<script src = "http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.js"></script>
<div id = "map" style = "width:900px; height:580px"></div>


<script>
    var map = new L.map('map', {center: [0,0], zoom: 5})
    map.addLayer(new L.TileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'))



    // what should go here to make the map equirectangular?


</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

replace this line:
`var map = new L.map('map', {center: [0,0], zoom: 5})`
with this line:
`var map = new L.map('map', {center: [0,0], zoom: 5, crs: L.CRS.EPSG4326})`

Doing so changes the crs (coordinate reference system) from the default mercator projection to equirectangular.

More generally this is a "map option". More map options can be found in the api:  https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#map-option

Comment: Do not forget to use a Tile Server that gives you tiles in the appropriate projection. OSM tiles are only in Web Mercator.